# java.lang.NullPointerException when made a required change to the code (Java Netbeans IDE 7.4 & JDK 1.7)

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe

My initial piece of code is the following.

```
public class JFrameAllMarks extends javax.swing.JFrame {


        public JFrameAllMarks() {
        initComponents();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrameAllMarks.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        showMark();

    }

 public ArrayList<Marks> markList1()
        {
            ArrayList<Marks> marksList = new ArrayList<>();

             try {   
                DBConnection obj = new DBConnection();

                String selectquery = "SELECT * FROM Marks";

                ResultSet rs = obj.getdata(selectquery);

                Marks objmk;

                while(rs.next())
                {
                    objmk = new Marks(rs.getString("StudentID"), rs.getString("StudentName"), rs.getString("SubjectID"), rs.getString("SubjectName"), rs.getString("BatchID"), rs.getInt("Marks"));
                    marksList.add(objmk);
                }
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JFrameAllMarks.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            return marksList;
        }


 public void showMark()
 {
     ArrayList<Marks> list = markList1();

     DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)jTableAllMarks.getModel();

     Object[] row = new Object[6];

     for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
     {
         row[0] = list.get(i).getStudentID();
         row[1] = list.get(i).getStudentName();
         row[2] = list.get(i).getSubjectID();
         row[3] = list.get(i).getSubjectName();
         row[4] = list.get(i).getBatchID();
         row[5] = list.get(i).getMarks();

         dtm.addRow(row);

     }
 }
```

And the required java class for the ArrayList in the above code.

```
package AllMarksList;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
class Marks {
    private String StudentID, StudentName, SubjectID, SubjectName, BatchID;
    private int Marks;

    public Marks (String StudentID, String StudentName, String SubjectID, String SubjectName, String BatchID, int Marks)
    {
        this.StudentID=StudentID;
        this.StudentName=StudentName;
        this.SubjectID=SubjectID;
        this.SubjectName=SubjectName;
        this.BatchID=BatchID;
        this.Marks=Marks;

     }


    public String getStudentID()
    {
        return StudentID;
    }

    public String getStudentName()
    {
        return StudentName;
    }

    public String getSubjectID()
    {
        return SubjectID;
    }

    public String getSubjectName()
    {
        return SubjectName;
    }

    public String getBatchID()
    {
        return BatchID;
    }

    public int getMarks()
    {
        return Marks;
    }

}
```

The above code executed correctly. It showed all data that resided in the "Marks" database table.

So, I copied and pasted this and the relevant class to create another JFrame and java class that functions the exact same way. Relevant changes were made to have distinct changes between the original and the copied JFrames and java classes.

In this new JFrame, I wanted to extract from the database, only the data that contained a certain Student ID.
So, I changed the select query to the following.

```
String selectquery = "SELECT * FROM Marks WHERE StudentID=S001";
```

And when executing this new code, I received the following errors.

```
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at StudentMarks.JFrameStudentAllMarks.markList1(JFrameStudentAllMarks.java:47)
    at StudentMarks.JFrameStudentAllMarks.showMark1(JFrameStudentAllMarks.java:63)
    at StudentMarks.JFrameStudentAllMarks.<init>(JFrameStudentAllMarks.java:30)
    at StudentMarks.JFrameStudentAllMarks$3.run(JFrameStudentAllMarks.java:224)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Tried making changes to the lines of code, pinpointed by the error.
But had no luck in solving this.

Would really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: My guess is that `DBConnection obj = new DBConnection();` is failing. Use a debugger to check it. Also, make sure your connection string is correct.

Comment: Also, [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](//stackoverflow.com/a/218510)

Comment: What is line 47?

Comment: Since you didn't show us the new code, how can we help?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp
Hi,
I can say the connection string is correct, because other jframes and classes are working fine with the above DBConnection object reference.
I'll check the question mentioned.

Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @NomadMaker
Hi,
The new code is exactly the same as the original code, except the "selectquery" statement. Changes made are mentioned above.

Comment: Do you check *everything* for null when it is returned? Especially the database objects, including the resultset.

Comment: @GreyFairer
Hi,
It refers to the following line

```
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    objmk = new Marks(rs.getString("StudentID"), rs.getString("StudentName"), rs.getString("SubjectID"), rs.getString("SubjectName"), rs.getString("BatchID"), rs.getInt("Marks"));
                    marksList.add(objmk);
                }
```

Comment: @NomadMaker
I think it does.
However, before adding "WHERE = S001" to the selectquery, the original code executed just fine.
I just can't understand the reason for this error.

Comment: Have you signed onto the database directly and checked if there is a student id 'S001'?

Comment: @NomadMaker
Yes. Below is an example.

StudentID StudentName SubjectID SubjectName BatchID Marks
S001       Jim Gordon SB003      C++ B001       66

Comment: @Weranjana De Silva I don't remember the exact syntax for sql, but shouldn't the S001 be surrounded by single quotes, like 'S001' ?

Comment: It's nice to see the effort people put into solving this, and that a solution was found. To make it more useful to the wider SO community, could you, @NomadMaker upgrade you comment to an answer? (& if you do, notify me)

Comment: Done. The answer is in place.

Answer (score 0):

Because you created the SQL query out of a Java String, you need to use SQL syntax. SQL uses single-quotes to delimit a string, so you need to add those into your query manually.

This is the string that is needed:

```
String selectquery = "SELECT * FROM Marks WHERE StudentID='S001'";
```